# Not able to load Application Context in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application wherein I am using that application to expose a SOAP webservice. I am using Apache CFX framework for SOAP impl in Spring boot app. I am using Annotation based approach.

I am facing issue in setting the Application Context from the Spring Boot Configuration file in one of the Beans. Below is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

The configuration file is as below.

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {

//All individual bean definitions should go here
@Autowired
ApplicationContext appContext;

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/soap-api/*");
}

@Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {
    return new SpringBus();
}


@Bean(name="IValidator")
public IValidator getValidator(){
    return new Validator();
}

@Bean(name="SOAPprocessImpl")
public IPSoap getService() {
    return new SOAPprocessImpl();
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), getService());
    endpoint.publish("/WS_1.0");
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation("process.wsdl");
    return endpoint;
}
```

Now I have the bean SOAPprocessImpl implementation in which I need to get the Application Context so that I can get handle to the Validator bean. I have declared SOAPprocessImpl as a bean in the configuraton file. The code is as below

```
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="com.test.IPSoap")
public class SOAPprocessImpl implements IPSoap, ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
        throws BeansException {
    context = ac;
}

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SOAPprocessImpl.class.getName());

private IValidator validator = (IValidator) context.getBean("IValidator"); // context is NULL here

public IRResponse GetBalance(TSSearchParams SearchParams) {

    // Some processing logic
    }
```

}

So the issue is that when I run the boot application by deploying to the embedded Tomcat then the Application Context is not getting set in the SOAPprocessImpl class even after implementing the ApplicationContextAware. I also tried Autowiring but that also is not working.

Strangely I tried to see if I can get the ApplicationContext in the Configuration file where all the bean are defined. Here it is getting setting properly.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue. I am new to Spring Boot and may have missed some configutaion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option(1):** To fix the issue, you need to use `@Configuration` **to register your `SOAPprocessImpl` bean to the Spring container** as shown below so that `ApplicationContext` object can be injected :

```
@Configuration
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="com.test.IPSoap")
public class SOAPprocessImpl implements IPSoap, ApplicationContextAware {

   private static ApplicationContext context;

   private IValidator validator;

   public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
     return context;
   }

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
      throws BeansException {
      SOAPprocessImpl.context = ac;
   }


   @PostConstruct//use PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     validator = (IValidator) context.getBean("IValidator");
   }


   //add your current code
}
```

The important point is that you can't use the `context` object until the bean is prepared by the container, so you need to use `@PostConstruct` method as shown above to initialise your variables.

**Option2 (recommended):**
The best approach is that you can use `@Autowired` to inject `IValidator` object into `SOAPprocessImpl` as shown below so that you don't need your `SOAPprocessImpl` bean to be aware of `ApplicationContextAware`. Spring container will inject the instance for the implementation provided for the `IValidator` class (provided it is under the packages of `@Componentscan`).

```
@Component
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="com.test.IPSoap")
public class SOAPprocessImpl implements IPSoap {

     private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SOAPprocessImpl.class.getName());


     @Autowired //spring directly injects this object
     private IValidator validator;

     public IRResponse GetBalance(TSSearchParams SearchParams) {
        // Some processing logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I tried your approach but still its not working. The context is still null.

Comment: which package `SOAPprocessImpl` resides?

Comment: SOAPprocessImpl resides in a different package. com.test.config and WebServiceConfiguration resides in other package. com.test.ws

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation. Its working now and I am able to get the validator instance from 2nd approach you suggested. have a great day my friend.